# Perform Single Selection of Row in UITableView with custom UITableViewCell ?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I know there are lot of answers to this question . But it didn't achieved the desired result . didDEselectrow is not working . I have a UIImageView which i have set to hidden True in cellforRowAtIndex. And when someone selects any row value for hidden is set to false .

**My main problem is when i select another row , the previous row status does not change and it also shows selected . I have attached the necessary snippet of my code ,Please check and help me through this . **

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    EventTypeTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Event_Type" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    if (cell.selectionStatus)
        [cell.selectEvent setHidden:NO];
    else
        [cell.selectEvent setHidden:YES];

    [cell.eventTypeName setText:[eventTypeName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 EventTypeTableViewCell *cell = (EventTypeTableViewCell *)[self.tableView    cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell.selectionStatus == TRUE)
    {
        cell.selectionStatus = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
]        cell.selectionStatus = TRUE;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    EventTypeTableViewCell *cell = (EventTypeTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.selectionStatus == FALSE)
    {
        //Do your stuff
        cell.selectionStatus = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        //Do your stuff
        cell.selectionStatus = FALSE;
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that didDeselect is not being called because you are allowing multiple selections in your tableView.

Have you set your table view's selection style to "single selection"?  You can either do it in interface builder/storyboard or you can do it programmatically:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
}
```

That way when you select another row it will deselect the old selection.  Also you can simplify your code and make everything look better by not calling [tableView reloadData] every time one cell's selected state changes.  The way I would suggest doing that is to change the hidden state of `selectEvent` within `EventTypeTableViewCell` whenever the cell's selection changes.

That leaves you with this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    EventTypeTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Event_Type" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.eventTypeName setText:[eventTypeName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

And some method overrides within your definition of `EventTypeTableViewCell`:

```
@implementation EventTypeTableViewCell

///  Your code ///

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    self.selectEvent.hidden = !selected;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
     [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```